# Custom Cursor Adapter ( get position )

Tags: android, custom-cursor

I want to set touchable for my image view and how i get position for image view of each line in list view ?

```
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_shipments, parent, false);


        return retView;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cursor` is already positioned at the exact row when called `newView` or `bindView`. All you need is set onClick or OnTouch listener:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_shipments, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Some code for `ViewHolder`:

```
public static class ViewHolder
    {
        private ImageView image;
        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This command really save a lot of time and i can understand the algorithm easily :)

Comment: excuse me, inside the view.onClickListener is able to use startacitivity or SettingActivity.getPreferencesStringValue? Because i want to link to other interface through this view.imageview.onclick :(

Answer (score -1):

@anil
Here my code in my View.OnClickListener

```
holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String abc = holder.tv1.getText().toString();
                String def = holder.tv2.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(abc + def);

                String lat = abc;
                String lng = def;
                String[] countryValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.str_array_country_values);
                String country = SettingsActivity.getPreferencesStringValue(CursorAdapterActivity.this, 
                        SettingsActivity.KEY_COUNTRY_CODE, "");
                String uri = "";

                if (country.equals(countryValues[0])){
                    uri = "http://api.map.baidu.com/marker?location=" + lat + "," + lng + "&zoom=15&title= &content= &output=html";
                }
                else{
                    uri = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + lat + "," + lng + "&z=15";    
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
            }

        });
```

Comment: this is not an activity ( just a class )

Comment: Use `context.startActivity...`. And ask another question for another problem)

Comment: `public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor)`